# Splitting loops and cache performance

Tags: c++, performance, caching

I've written some C++ code to average the nearest-neighbour values of elements in a 2D array, and write the result into the corresponding element of a second array. This is iterated many times, with the pointers from grid1 and grid2 being swapped every iteration. Typical values of yMax and xMax are ~500. I've written two versions of this code, one with the code to populate grid2 in the same loop as the difference calculation, and one with the loops split:

```
double difference;
double diffSquared;
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= yMax + 1; ++y) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= xMax + 1; ++x) {
            grid2[y][x] = (grid1[y - 1][x] + grid1[y][x + 1] + grid1[y + 1][x] + grid1[y][x - 1])/4.0;
            difference = grid1[y][x] - grid2[y][x];
            diffSquared += difference*difference;
        }
    }
    *Record difference, then swap grid1 and grid2 pointers*
}
```

and:

```
double difference;
double diffSquared;
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= yMax + 1; ++y) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= xMax + 1; ++x) {
            grid2[y][x] = (grid1[y - 1][x] + grid1[y][x + 1] + grid1[y + 1][x] + grid1[y][x - 1])/4.0;
        }
    }
    for (int y = 1; y <= yMax + 1; ++y) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= xMax + 1; ++x) {
            difference = grid1[y][x] - grid2[y][x];
            diffSquared += difference*difference;
        }
    }
    *Record difference, then swap grid1 and grid2 pointers*
}
```

With compiler optimizations turned on, the first version of the code is unsurprisingly faster. However, with optimizations turned off (-O0 in g++), the second version with split loops is reliably faster. The only explanation I can think of is that this is cache related, and that the extra access to *difference* and *diffSquared* somehow cause useful values to be evicted, but surely the cache is large enough to hold these extra values. What could be going on here? Are the multiple cache levels potentially at play?

Also, any advice on further improving the cache performance of this algorithm is welcome, especially regarding the accesses to neighbours on adjacent rows.

Comment: How do you define `grid1` and `grid2`?

Comment: double** grid = new double*[yMax + 2];

followed by a for loop to initialize each row with:

grid[y] = new double[xMax + 2];

Comment: Every row in that structure is its own memory block. No guarantee of locality, so you may have improved cache performance if you use a 1D array and manually index `row * num_columns + column`. Good example of a simple wrapper class that does this here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Comment: The array index values are out of bounds in many places. To loop through an array with `xMax + 2` elements, the loop should be `for (int x = 0; x < xMax + 2; ++x)`. Same for the loop over `y`. And with that fixed, accessing `grid[y][x+1]` and grid[y+1][x]` will still go out of bounds on the last pass through each loop.

Comment: That's an error with how I simplified by code to post here, I've fixed it now. The idea is that the values at the grid boundary are fixed, so are read as nearest neighbours but not overwritten.